# how to search on key down with angular 10?

Tags: arrays, angular, search, filter

i know its a noob question but i forgot how this syntax works... i have tried few things but it didnt really work... can someone help me out?

i have this array:

```
products = [
{name: banana},
{name: apple},
{name: orange}
]
```

and i have this search input

```
<input (keydown)="filterProducts($event)" placeholder="Ex. Banana">
```

this is my function

```
  filterProducts({target: {value}}) {
    this.products.filter(filtered => {
       const filter = filtered.name.includes(value)
      console.log(filter)
    })
  }
```

what i am getting in my console log is just true or false but
i want to get a new array containing only the items that their name starts with the letters of the search input... thanks!

note: no using pipes

Comment: You should follow the [Tour of Heroes Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#search-by-name) on the angular.io site. They also demonstrate [how you could implement a search](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#search-by-name) but searching is done server side. You could easily swap that for client side searching, just search on [so] how to filter an array as there are plenty of questions and answers about that topic.

Comment: but they all use pipes im not allowed to use pipes

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgluj1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: this is with a pipe also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filtered.name.includes(value)` is a boolean function, so it is showing you bool in your `console.log`

if you do

```
 filterProducts({target: {value}}) {
    const filteredProducts = this.products.filter(filtered=>filtered.name.includes(value))
    console.log(filteredProducts) // this prints the array of filtered
  }
```

you will see that the array gets filtered

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing my implementation using debounce directive. May be helpful someone.

```js
import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  search: any;
  products = [{ name: "banana" }, { name: "apple" }, { name: "orange" }];
  searchResult: any;

  onSearch(event: any) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    if (value.length >= 3) {
      this.searchResult = this.products.filter(filtered =>
        filtered.name.includes(value)
      );
    }
    console.log(this.searchResult);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" [(ngModel)]="search" appDebounce (debounce)="onSearch($event)" [delay]="300" />
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pqbttb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts